# Is there a way to populate mdDialog fields after the Dialog shows?

Tags: javascript, html, mddialog

I have a simple mdDialog for editing form entries, that pops up when you double-click a grid row. The dialog appears and everything works, except I'd like to populate the fields in the dialog with the contents of the grid row. The problem is that I'm not sure where to actually do this, and every spot I've tried so far is accessed before the Dialog has actually been shown, so the HTML elements inside the dialog don't exist yet to be populated. Here's the method that calls the dialog:

```
$scope.showUpdateDialog = function(data) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: UpdateDialogController,
        scope: $scope.$new(),
        templateUrl: 'js/admin/UpdateUsersDialog.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        clickOutsideToClose:true,
        fullscreen:true
    })
    .then(function(answer) {
        $scope.status = 'Updated User';
    }, function() {
        $scope.status = 'Update User Failed';
    });
};
```

And here is the controller for it:

```
function UpdateDialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    $scope.answer = function(answer) {
        $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };

    $scope.add = function(dialogdata) {
      // For clarity I removed the contents of what happens with the add, as this part works fine.
    };
}
```

Inside that templateUrl: 'js/admin/UpdateUsersDialog.html' are several elements, that all look like this:

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updatelogin"
            placeholder="Enter Name" data-ng-model="dialogdata.login" disabled />
```

I thought that the data-ng-model bit would take care of it (dialogdata.login etc. are all assigned variables before the dialog is kicked off) but it doesn't, so I was attempting to force it by doing something like this:

```
    var ulogin = document.getElementById('updatelogin');
    ulogin.setInnerHTML(content.login);
```

...but since the elements don't exist yet the 'ulogin' var keeps coming back as null. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some babbaging I figured something out, maybe this can help others who hit a similar problem. The solution for me was to put everything into the onRowDoubleClicked method, which is called in the ag-grid when I double click a row in the grid:

```
function onRowDoubleClicked() {
    var selectedRowNode = $scope.UserTableGrid.api.getSelectedNodes()[0];
    var data = selectedRowNode.data;
    $scope.login = data.login;
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.email = data.email;
    $scope.type = data.roles;
    $scope.userId = $scope.getUserId($scope.login);
    showUDialog(data);
        function showUDialog(data) {
            $scope.email = data.email;
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: UpdateDialogController,
                scope: $scope.$new(),
                templateUrl: 'js/admin/UpdateUsersDialog.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose:true,
                fullscreen:true
            })
            .then(function(answer) {
                $scope.status = 'Updated User';
            }, function() {
                $scope.status = 'Update User Failed';
            });         
        }

        function UpdateDialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
            $scope.hide = function() {
                $mdDialog.hide();
            };
            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $mdDialog.cancel();
            };
            $scope.answer = function(answer) {
                $mdDialog.hide(answer);
            };
            $scope.add = function() {

                //Close the Dialog
                $scope.answer("Completed");
                var userJson = {
                        "name" : $scope.name,
                        "login" : $scope.login,
                        "password" : "",
                        "roles" : $scope.type,
                        "email" : $scope.email,
                        "tpbUserId" : $scope.userId
                };
                var url = 'RobotDataInterface/User/updateUser';
                var data = JSON.stringify(userJson);
                $http.post(url, data).then(
                        function success(response) {
                            $scope.addUserCallback(response);
                        }, 
                        function failure(response) {
                            $scope.generalRestFailureCallback(response);
                        }
                );
            };
            $scope.addUserCallback = function(data) {
                console.log("User Updated!");
                $scope.loadTableData();
            }
        }   
}
```

This fixed what was a scoping issue, and allowed the fields in the templateUrl to get populated by tying them to those same values:

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
            placeholder="Enter Name" data-ng-model="name" />
```